# How to Iterate to output data to Google Sheets with App-Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

Using Google App Script, when I used Logger.log() the for loop iterates properly and I get results for each value. When I try to output this to a google sheet only the last value for each variable is output over and over again for the number of goals.length.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
function listGoals() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var filterList = Analytics.Management.Goals.list(accountId, webPropertyId, profileId)
      var goals = filterList.items;
        for (var i = 0, goal; goal = goals[i]; i++) {
            var accountId = goal.accountId;
            var propertyId = goal.webPropertyId;
            var goalNumber = goal.id;
            var goalName = goal.name;

            Logger.log('accountId: ' + accountId);
            Logger.log('profileId: ' + propertyId);
            Logger.log('goal number: ' + goalNumber);
            Logger.log('goal name: ' + goalName);
            //Logger.log prints for each result

            sheet.getRange(1,1,goals.length).setValue(goalNumber);
            sheet.getRange(1,2,goals.length).setValue(goalName);
            //this only prints out the last value of goalNumber and goalName to the sheet

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't only print the last results, it just keeps overwriting the old result with the new one. 
`goals.length` only helps if you then supply an array of arrays containing the values looking as such:

```
[[1, "Goal 1"], 
 [2, "Goal 2"]]
```

If you want to print out a list of `goalNumber` and `goalName` you need to offset the cell to write in every time.
something like

```
sheet.getRange(1+i,1).setValue(goalNumber);
sheet.getRange(1+i,2).setValue(goalName);
```

---

To speed up the process a bit and not do two calls for every goal you can store the id name pairs as arrays within an array and do one final `setValues` call after the loop finishes executing.

```
function listGoals() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var filterList = Analytics.Management.Goals.list(accountId, webPropertyId, profileId)
  var goals = filterList.items;
  var goalsToWrite = [];

  for (var i = 0, goal; goal = goals[i]; i++) {
    goalsToWrite.push([goal.id, goal.name]);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, goals.length, 2).setValues(goalsToWrite);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for also providing the 2nd example with the setValues() as well.